# Issue with my website and its styling

Tags: html, css

My website is [VivasCoaching](http://www.vivascoaching.com). I have been trying to eliminate some of the space on sides for the middle_column and right_column so that it looks a little more condensed but I am not too sure how to go about doing that. I also made a linkswrapper div so that I could add a background color to the div that my navigation sits in but I can't seem to get it working. Here is my code:

```css
html{
   height:100%;
   width:100%
}

header{
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-bottom:5px;
}

body{

   font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
}

h1,h2,h3{
   color: #112C84;
}

a:link {
   color: #112C84;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 120%;
}



/*-------NAV STYLING------------*/

#mainlinks li{
   float:left;
   margin-left:120px;
}



/*---------- COLUMN STYLING ----------*/

.linkswrapper{
  background-color: red;
}

.middle_column{
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   width:70%;
   margin:2px;
   margin-left: 20px;
   padding:10px;
}

.right_column{
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   width:10%;
   margin:5px;
}

/*---------- MOBILE --------------*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Vivas Coaching-Main</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/normalize.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="Images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="465" height="135">
  </header>
  <div class="linkswrapper">
    <nav id="mainlinks">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Main">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="courses.html" title="Courses">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.html" title="Register">Register</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div> 
  <div class="middle_column">
    <img src="Images/SAT_summer_flyer.jpg" alt="SAT_summer_flyer" style=" width: 80%; height: auto;">
    <footer>
      <p>&copy;VivasCoaching 2016</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <div class="right_column">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <p>(646)316-8481/<br>(403)718-0159</p>
    <p>Please fill out the information below and we will get back to you as soon as possible!<p>
    <form method="post" action="callback.php">
      <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
      <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" />
      <label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
      <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" />
      <label for="email">Email: <span class="required"></span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
      <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
      <label for="message"> Message:  <span class="required"></span></label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="25" rows="10" placeholder="Type your message here!"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want some gap on side of right coloumn and mid coloumn??

Comment: I want to eliminate some of the space that is there now but I am not sure how to do it. I want to condense the page a bit. I tried messing around with the width values for the columns but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your image to `100%` or reduce you `middle_column's width`

```
<div class="middle_column">
    <img src="Images/SAT_summer_flyer.jpg" alt="SAT_summer_flyer" style="width: 100%;height: auto;">
    <footer>
        <p>©VivasCoaching 2016</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

and about right column there is width set at `10%` if middle_column's width is `70%` then it should be `30%`;
change this into css.

`.right_column{width:30%;}`

`.linkswrapper` set height/ padding for this to show background color.

```
.linkswrapper{height:30px;}
```

**NOTE:** i think your footer should also out of from the `middle_column`.

Comment: I tried taking it out and adding it below everything in the HTML but it is appearing off to the side instead of below :/

Comment: `footer{clear: both;}` then you need to align it to center i hope you can do that by your self @Fate

Comment: For to increasing width of your right_column to `30%` its is necessary to remove margins of middle & right both column

Comment: The reason I have my right_column to 10% is because if I add any more it won't align to the left nicely the way it is right now. It will fall underneath my middle column.

Comment: ok. but your content are overflowing from the container. take a deep look at `input` fields. `max-width:100%` for inputs you will need it letter.

and i have a question for you. **why you're not using any frameworks like bootstrap?**

Comment: I am not sure how to use Bootstrap and when I made this website I didn't know of its existence so this site is built from the ground up.

Comment: all right good luck@Fate i asked you because like this you will face problem if you need to work on mobile compatibility.

Comment: @Guatam  Jha is there anyway to make it mobile compatible once I finish it later on? do I HAVE to use boostrap? Can't I do it myself from the ground up?

Comment: you can do it later easily. just need to learn media query. i recommend you to learn bootstrap for your next projects

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the background not showing is that you haven't provided any height for your 'linkswrapper' div. Give it some height in your css, and it will show that red color.

```
.linkswrapper {
    height: 40px;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I added bootstrap for responsiveness and also it clears the white space try this code

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Vivas Coaching-Main</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/normalize.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

 <header class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="465" height="135">
 </header>

 <div class="linkswrapper col-md-12" style="text-align:center">
  <nav id="mainlinks">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="index.html" title="Main">Main</a></li>
         <li><a href="aboutus" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="courses.html" title="Courses">Courses</a></li>
         <li><a href="register.html" title="Register">Register</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
 </div> 

 <div class="middle_column col-md-8 thumbnail" style="border-style:none;">
 <img src="images/SAT_summer_flyer.jpg" alt="SAT_summer_flyer" style=" width: 80%; height: auto;">
 <footer>
  <p>&copy;VivasCoaching 2016</p>
    </footer>
 </div>

<div class="right_column col-md-4" style="border-style:none;">
 <h2>Contact Us</h2>
 <p>(646)316-8481/<br>(403)718-0159</p>
 <p>Please fill out the information below and we will get back to you as soon as possible!<p>

 <form method="post" action="callback.php">

      <label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
      <input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" />

      <label for="lastname">Last Name: </label>
      <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control"/>

      <label for="email">Email: <span class="required"></span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-control"/>

      <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
      <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here" class="form-control">
      
      <label for="message"> Message:  <span class="required"></span></label>
      
      <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="25" rows="10" placeholder="Type your message here!" class="form-control"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
 </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the boostrap code but it didn't work :/ everything went haywire on the website so I switched it back.

Answer (score 0):

middle_column's width is 70% so you need to set right column width to 30% so that it will come side by side and looks perfect.

`.middle_column { width:70%; }
.right_column  { width:30%; }`